# #Error in Column With both Text and Numeric Values in ssrs reports

Tags: reporting-services, report

In my report for one field i have both numeric and text values.( i.e 10.546 and "vary")
So when i apply CDec function for this field values i get #error where i have filed value as "Vary" .

10.6572 10.6572
Vary    #Error

i tried expression "
                =IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!price.Value),
               CDec(Fields!price.Value),
              "Fields!price.Value)"

but it is not working.
i checked in net in most of the cases all telling to write function, unfortunately in my project that is not allowed.
so is their any way i can resolve this "#Error"  using expression.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.
          =iif(IsNumeric(Fields!EUnit.Value), VAL(Fields!EUnit.Value),Fields!EUnit.Value)

this is working fine to me.

Ref : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac2c9db4-85a5-44a8-909b-1ee09791542e/ssrs-check-if-the-field-value-is-numeric-or-not?prof=required